# Ideas on how to create a mold or stencil of lettered emblem on back of vehicle?

Tags: material-selection, tool-selection, technique-selection, casting, silicone-mold

[image: automobile lettered emblem]

Apologies, as I'm sure this is an unusual question. I'm wondering if anyone could come up with a way to create a stencil, or molding of the letters on this vehicle, with materials or techinques that would be safe for the car. If letters (and adhesive) are removed, I would like to be able to reattach them in the exact spot. What comes to mind is a large paper and tracing, and silicone sealant that I saw from this youtube video [How to Make a Mold (CHEAP)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1H42C3nW_nw&t=393s).
I'm open to any creative ideas.

Comment: Interesting question, but an idea of the final goal could lead to more creative answers than what I've been able to come up with

Comment: What's the goal? What do you plan to make the letters from? What do you plan to do with them? How many duplicates do you need to make? Are you restricted to the letters that are on the car, without removal of them?

Answer (score 2):

It depends what sort of quality do you need, and whether you really want a mould or a stencil.

The former needs very good (and thick) mould release, very well applied, as car logo badges typically have a little undercut that your mould material could get into (this also suggests silicone rather than something brittle like plaster). I'd consider applying grease where the letters meet the bodywork, with an oil-based releae. I'd test both on a tucked-away bit of paintwork first. Moulding each letter separately, and assembling the moulds to get the final shape would reduce the amount of material needed, deal with the probably curved surface, and if one letter gets stuck due to flowing under the shape, you only have to redo that one

A stencil might be achievable with brass rubbing techniques on thin card, followed by cutting with a scalpel. Alternatively see if you could download and print the logo (over several sheets of paper) and cut it out.

Stencils in general work better for designs without loops, but by using repositionable spray glue you could reproduce the logo pictured. Imperfections in the positioning of the insides of the loops are very easily spotted.

Depending on what you want to do with it, a stencil may have the issue that the letters on the car are moulded, and have a draw angle. The face that attaches to the car will be slightly bigger than the outer face, so a stencil matching the latter won't slip over the letters.